# PHPStorm phpunit loads configuration other project

Tags: phpunit, phpstorm

When running a test using PHPStorm it loads a configuration from an other project.

```
/usr/bin/php /private/var/folders/jv/rch25xnj6y3cl_yf4s6qq64m0000gn/T/ide-phpunit.php --bootstrap /Users/reneterstegen/Sites/www.domain1.com/app/bootstrap.php.cache --configuration /Users/reneterstegen/Sites/www.one-of-my-other-projects.com/app/phpunit.xml.dist --filter "/::itLoadsTheForm( .*)?$/" Stegeman\Bundle\SearchBundle\Tests\SearchControllerTest /Users/reneterstegen/Sites/www.domain1.com/src/Stegeman/Bundle/SearchBundle/Tests/SearchControllerTest.php
```

This causes a fatal:

```
Class 'JMS\SerializerBundle\JMSSerializerBundle' not found in /Users/reneterstegen/Sites/www.one-of-my-other-projects.com/app/AppKernel.php on line 21
```

This makes sense since the project I am testing is nog using this bundle.

I've already set the default configuration file and default bootstrap file settings in the PHPUnit section in preferences.

Question: Can somebody tell me how to change the configuration used by phpunit in PHPStorm?

Answer (score 0):

> Can somebody tell me how to change the configuration used by phpunit in PHPStorm?

You can always specify custom ("alternative") config file per Run/Debug Configuration -- it will be used instead of Default one that you have set in Preferences.

https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PHPUnit+support+in+PhpStorm#PHPUnitsupportinPhpStorm-3.CreatingaRunConfiguration

[image]

Here you have to tick the **"Use alternative configuration file"** and specify full path to it (either manually or via **"..."** button). NOTE: if you click on a button next to "..." one it will allow you to edit paths to Default config files (the ones from Preferences).

Please note that if you have defined your bootstrap file in that Default section as well .. it will also be used and AFAIK you cannot override it. It will be better if you provide bootstrap file in actual config file.